# python: read in text file in numpy.loadtxt format splitting integers by digits

Tags: python

My program reads a text file formatted like this with spaces between each digit:

```
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 0
```

My current code to read the text file is

```
G = numpy.loadtxt(filename, int)
```

If I print(G), the output looks like this:

```
[[0 1 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]]
```

I received new txt files that I need to run on my program, but the text files do not have spaces between each digit like this:

```
011
100
100
```

I would like to be able to read these new txt files into a 2D list without commas exactly like before. I tried this:

```
filename = open(file, "r")
G = []
gr = filename.readline().strip()
while gr:
    gr = list(map(int,str(gr)))
    G.append(gr)
    gr = filename.readline().strip()
```

When I print(G) it looks like this and doesn't work with my program:

```
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
```

Is there a way to read these new text files without spaces between each digit into a list with the same formatting as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have already is almost working.  Just add one more line at the bottom of your code, like this:

```
G = numpy.array(G)
```